# Google places autocomplete from client-side app

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Anyone wise to whether it is possible to use the google places autocomplete api from a client side app.

I tried to access it with a jsonp request to the following url..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=#{input}&types(regions)&language=en_en&key=MY_API_KEY&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK"

And I get this response

"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 94.33.38.138, with referer: http://localhost:3000/"

What I'm finding out is that the autocomplete api requires a server key, and can only be accessed from the backend. Is that correct? Or is there another way to access it from a browser?

I need to combine the results from the places autocomplete with another autocomplete list on the same input field so the google places autocomplete widget is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may request the predictions via the autocomplete-service of the places-library of the  javascript-API( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service )...no key is required and it may be requested from client-side